# Enum parameter taking passing incorrect values in Visual Studio Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

We have this very strange error in Asp.Net MVC 4 Razor whereby within the View, we have the following code:

```
@Html.InlineEditingContentText(CS.General_v4.Enums.HtmlTagName.Span, VisitGozo.Enums.VisitGozoEnums.ContentTextIdentifier.MasterPage_Weather_Title, "weather-widget-title masterpage-widget-title")
```

`InlineEditingContentText` is an extension method which we have internally.  The 2nd parameter being passed is an enumeration parameter and as you can see from above, the value is `VisitGozo.Enums.VisitGozoEnums.ContentTextIdentifier.MasterPage_Weather_Title`.  Now when you debug into the extension method `InlineEditingContentText`, the actual 2nd parameters being received is not `VisitGozo.Enums.VisitGozoEnums.ContentTextIdentifier.MasterPage_Weather_Title` but `VisitGozo.Enums.VisitGozoEnums.ContentTextIdentifier.MasterPage_Header_LoggedOutText` which happens to be the next value of the ContentTextIdentifier enumeration after `VisitGozo.Enums.VisitGozoEnums.ContentTextIdentifier.MasterPage_Weather_Title`.

We are not assigning values to the enumerations and so their respective `int` values increment after each other automatically.

- Strangely enough, if we load the exact same project on another workstation, this works fine.
- Also, if we perform some changes to the View (like just add a whitespace) and save, this also works fine.

Any possible insight into why this strange issue is happening?

---

Edit #1: Also, when we uploaded the website on the deployment server, after compiling using same workstation, the error was carried over as well

Edit #2: 2013-10-22 > We are still getting this same problem, even when then deploying the files on the actual production server, such incorrect enum values are being carried over.  The only way to solve the issue is to delete the Views from the server / locally, and re-overwriting them again.  Any idea how we can solve this issue?  We shouldn't be caching Views so can't really understand why this is happening?  Would appreciate any form of help!

Comment: Sounds like it was possibly last compiled when the enum had a different set of values.

Comment: @JonSkeet, we rebuilt and cleaned the entire solution, yet still the error stayed

Comment: I suspect it didn't clean fully - that would explain *everything*, including adding a whitespace to the view fixing it. I suspect there are any number of places that the compiled view could be cached without you realizing it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Any suggestion towards what we could do in order to fix such an issue of views being cached?  This is happening locally on the workstation using the Asp.Net development server where the solution is being run & built every time before running.  We have even tried removing Asp.Net temporary files, and still problem persisted.

Comment: So having "fixed" it with the whitespace change, it breaks again? That does sound very odd...

Comment: Since we are using SVN, we checked out the entire folder again and it worked but still am afraid to encounter such problems again as it took us several hours to identify such problem and possible resolution towards it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cached files have not been cleaned. It might happen occasionally.

- If you use IIS delete corresponding Temporary ASP.NET folder. For example, if your project is 64bit Framwork 4.0 then path would be:
  %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
- If you use IIS Express or similar you might need to stop it and start again.

Updating Razor file forced dynamic compilation and that solved the your issue.

Comment: I tried to clear temp asp.net folder but still didn't work out.  I restarted Visual Studio and even restarted workstation and still nothing

Comment: If you use IIS that's 100% solution to clear dll cache. Perhaps you deleted wrong folder? Check your app-pool settings.

Comment: We use the Asp.Net development server through Visual Studio

Comment: In those cases stooping ASP.NET development server in Taskbar works. Then Visual Studio starts new one with cleared cache. Temporary ASP.NET folder is used only by IIS.

Comment: This is even happening if you have your workstation switched on, load visual studio locally and run it through IIS express / Visual Studio so I can't imagine that it will still be cached?